# the speed of my animation increases the more i press the movement keys. How can i slow it down or increase it gradually?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So i am creating a simple mario game in the browser using canvas and everything is going well so far except for the fact that my canvas speeds up like crazy as the game progresses.

```
"var marioX = 283 ;
var marioY = 365 ;
var gravityfunction = function (){
    if (marioY <365){
        marioY += 0.5 
    } else{
        marioY = marioY;
    }
}



bg.src = "/images/background.png";
playerLeftImg.src = "images/marioleft.png";
playerRightImg.src = "images/marioright.png";
obstacle.src = "images/obstacle.png"
```

called a event listener below:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSquare, false);

// Create Obstacles 
var obstacles = [];

obstacles[0] = {
    x: 925,
    y: 280,
}
//Game Over Function 
function gameOver(){
    if(marioX === obstacleX && marioY === 365){
        alert("game over")
    }
}
// Game function: to draw out everything
```

My draw function which basically animates everything out. 
I am assuming i have to add something to this to fix the problem?

```
function draw(){

c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

c.drawImage(bg,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);


//create a for loop to create obstacles 
    for(let i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++){

    c.drawImage(obstacle,obstacles[i].x,360, 50, 30);

    obstacles[i].x -= 1;

    if(obstacles[i].x==310){
        obstacles.push({
            x : 925,
            y : 280,
        })
    }
}

    c.drawImage(playerRightImg, marioX ,marioY);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);  
    gravityfunction();
    gameOver();
};
draw();
```

this is the function that listens to my event and decides what action to take

```
function moveSquare(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37:
        // left key is pressed
        if(marioX > 0) {
            marioX -= 70;
            marioY-=0;
            console.log(marioX)
        } else if (marioX<= 0){
            marioX-= 0
            marioY -= 0
        }
        draw();
        break;
    case 32:
        // space key is pressed
        if(marioY > 0){
            (marioY-= 160);
            marioX += 0;
        } else if(marioY <=0){
            marioY -= 0;
            marioX -= 0;
        }
        draw();

        break;
    case 39:
        // right key is pressed
        if(marioX < 925 ){
            marioY+= 0;
            marioX += 70;
            console.log(marioX)
        } else if(marioX >= 925){
            marioY -= 0;
            marioX += 0;
            console.log(marioX)
        }
        draw();

        break;
    case 40:
        if(marioY < 365){
            marioY += 70;
            marioX -=0;
            console.log(marioY)
        } else if(marioY >= canvas.height){
            marioY -= 0;
            marioY -=0;
        }
        draw();
        // down key is pressed
        break;
        };
        }

        draw();""
```

Comment: Instead of pasting quote code into the question, please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58212906/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]. Remember to click TIDY before safving. You can get images from placeholder.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider detaching the drawing function from the user input. 
The keydown event handler should only update Mario's position. 
Your draw function should be called in a loop and just render the current position at each iteration.
This way, your animation speed will not depend on the user input speed.

Comment: This worked but do you know why? like i want to understand the logic behind it and not just get a working game. Thank you

Comment: I guess it works like that tree from the story. It should be able to fall and make noise even if no one is listening. And it should not fall twice just because someone is there listening with two ears.

Comment: I am joking (am I ?), but users can click at different speeds, computers can respond to a click at different speeds. You cannot rely on them for things that takes time.